# Changing the value of a reference to a static variable in a function

Tags: c++, function

Consider the following code snippet in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static int a = 10;
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int &y = fun();
    y += 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `40`

How is output of the code snippet given above justified?

Comment: You don't use a function pointer anywhere in here. Look up how `static` works

Comment: What output were you expecting? Also I think you're more confused about how _references_ work than function pointers, which you don't use in your program.

Comment: Despite the misleading use of whitespace in `int &fun()`, the ampersand symbol refers to the `int` (therefore declaring the return type of `fun` as `int&` – “reference to `int`”) and does not “take the address of `fun`”.  This has nothing to do with a function pointer.  Maybe this was confusing you?

Comment: I cannot Expect a valid output, never encountered this type of snippet before. please justify output, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fun` isn't a function pointer, it's a nullary function that returns an `int&`. Specifically, it returns a reference to a `static int` named `a`.

So what your program does is:

```
int &y = fun(); // this is the first call to fun, so we initialize a.
                // it now has a value of 10, and we return a reference to it
                // so y is a reference to the static variable local to fun()

y += 30;        // y == 40
                // since y is a reference to "fun::a", a is now 40 too

cout << fun();  // a is static, so it will only get initialized once.
                // that first line is effectively a NOOP, so fun() just
                // returns a reference to it. which has a value of 40.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using function pointers, but just storing the result of a call to `fun` in a reference.

`a` is *static* variable, and you are initialising a reference to that variable. A reference is just another name for `a`, in this case, so that's why modifying the value of the reference `y`, you modify also the value `a`, which is static, that means that its value is preserved from call to call.